# How to connect to remote address with UdpSocket?

Tags: sockets, rust, https, udp

I'd like to send an HTTPS request over UDP to a server on the internet (where I don't know if the server supports HTTPS over UDP). As a toy example, right now, I'm trying to send a GET request to http://httpbin.org/get. How do I do this?

Right now, I'm doing this in Rust, and my code looks like this:

```
use std::net::ToSocketAddrs;

fn main() {
    let socket = std::net::UdpSocket::bind("127.0.0.1:34254").unwrap();
    let remote_addr: std::net::SocketAddr = "httpbin.org:80".to_socket_addrs().unwrap().next().unwrap();
    socket.connect(remote_addr).unwrap();

    let msg = "GET /get HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: httpbin.org\r\naccept: application/json\r\n\r\n\r\n";
    socket.send(msg.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    let mut buf = [0; 5000];
    let num_bytes = socket.recv(&mut buf).unwrap();
    println!("recieved {} bytes: {:?}", num_bytes, std::str::from_utf8(&buf[..num_bytes]));
}
```

However, when I run the code I get the following output (this happens on `socket.connect(...)`):

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 22, kind: InvalidInput, message: "Invalid argument" }', ...
```

Is what I'm doing even possible? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I feel like your question has two different topics. "How do I connect to a server via UDP" and "How do I switch to HTTPS". Please only ask one question. Your title asks one thing, but your content asks a different thing.

Comment: HTTPS over UDP is a standardized protocol: HTTP/3. It does not really resemble HTTP/1, i.e. you cannot simply send HTTP/1 messages over UDP.

Comment: @Finomnis Good point. My original hope was to get this toy example working and then ask the question about how to upgrade to HTTPS... Will ask a follow-up question on this later, if it's helpful.

Comment: I cleaned up the title to focus on connecting the UDP socket since that is a valuable question, your current hurdle, and what the (accepted) answers have focused on. Hopefully your UDP/HTTPS adventures continue! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Finomnis pointed out, there are several questions here so I will choose to answer only one of them - namely how to fix the error you are experiencing.

Your issue comes from binding the UDP socket on `127.0.0.1`. Since this is a local address, the socket will only bind to the local interface and you will be able to communicate with local hosts only.
As you want to connect to a remote server, you should instead bind to `0.0.0.0`, which is a shorthand for all network interfaces:

```
let socket = std::net::UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:34254").unwrap();
```

With this change the code no longer panics, but instead hangs on `socket.recv()`.
Since it's unlikely that `httpbin.org` is ready to respond to this request, you will probably never get a response.

PS: When saying HTTPS over UDP, you might be thinking of [HTTP/3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/3) which is indeed based on UDP, but is a much more complicated protocol that HTTP/1.

Comment: Thank you! Does the port I'm binding on matter?

Comment: No; usually you shouldn't specify it and let the OS pick one.

Answer (score 2):

You can't send a message to an external IP address from a socket that is bound to `127.0.0.1`.

Tell the operating system that it should figure out where to bind it instead:

```rust
let socket = std::net::UdpSocket::bind((Ipv4Addr::UNSPECIFIED, 0)).unwrap();
```

---

Apart of that, you most likely won't get an answer, because `http`/`https` usually does not use `UDP`, it uses `TCP`. The webservers will not listen on `UDP` port `80`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well, Finomnis! If I had sufficient reputation points, I would upvote this as well.

Comment: I am aware that HTTP/HTTPS usually use TCP. I was curious if I could make UDP work as a transport as well.

Comment: Well, you have to use what the server offer.